# srcSet in Image component is not working and it is not displaying right image in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

here is my code of next js

```
import React from "react";
import style from "@/styles/Home.module.css";
import Image from "next/image";

function index() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <Image
            src="/image/banner900x400.jpg"
            alt="Govind Hand Print Banner"
            fill={true}
            className={style.img}
            srcSet="/image/banner900x400.jpg 900w, /image/bedsheet.png 522w"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default index;
```

**css**

```
.img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 80% !important;
  position: relative !important;
  height: unset !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .img {
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 90% !important;
  }
}
```

in output i only get banner900x400.jpg on all screen sizes. in vs code this is giving error like this " Property 'srcSet' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes "
i try srcset and srcSet none of these working. try to find answer on web but cant find anything

Comment: next/image automatically generate srcset, there is no need to pass it as property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this API reference - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image

Next.js Image component does not support passing `srcSet` like how you are trying to do. You can handle this using JavaScript, e.g., using a custom loader function or storing the image URL in a state variable.

Comment: i am trying to follow this tutorial  https://web.dev/learn/design/responsive-images/#sizes this link is mention in next js docs

Comment: There native img tag is used. You are using Next.js Image component.